# prevent xss on input fields?

Tags: php, escaping, preg-replace, htmlpurifier

1-i have a form which has name family email birthday(which is a select) and gender which is two diffrent radio buttons one for male and another one obviously is for female.
now please can someone explain me how to prevent xss attacks on this fields in php?
my form data is like this

```
<form action="register.php" method="post">
    <div>
        <table>
        <tr><td><?php echo $lang['5']; ?> :</td><td> <input type="text" name="name" maxlength="254" class="required" /></td></tr>
        <tr><td><?php echo $lang['6']; ?> :</td><td> <input type="text" name="family" maxlength="254" class="required" /></td></tr>
        <tr><td><?php echo $lang['59']; ?> :</td><td> <input type="text" name="email" maxlength="254" class="required" /></td></tr>
        <tr><td><?php echo $lang['74']; ?> :</td><td> <input type="text" name="repeat" maxlength="254" class="required" /></td></tr>
        <tr><td><?php echo $lang['60']; ?> :</td><td><input type="password" name="password"/></td></tr>
        <tr>
        <td><?php echo $lang['8'] ?> :</td>
        <td>
        <select name="day">
        <option><?php echo $lang['9'] ?></option>
        <?php 
        for($i=1;$i<=31;$i++){
        echo "<option value=\"{$i}\">{$i}</option>\n"; 
        }
        ?>
        </select>
        <select name="month">
        <?php 
        for($i=0;$i<=12;$i++){
        $i = str_pad($i,2,"0",STR_PAD_LEFT);
        echo "<option value=\"{$i}\">";T(1,$i);echo "</option>\n"; 
        }
        ?>
        </select>
        <select name="year">
        <option><?php echo $lang['11'] ?></option>
        <?php 
        for($i=1300;$i<=1373;$i++){
        if($i == $birthdate['0']){
        echo "<option value=\"{$i}\" selected=\"selected\">{$i}</option>\n"; 
        }else{
        echo "<option value=\"{$i}\">{$i}</option>\n"; 
        }
        }
        ?>
        </select>
        </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        male : <input type="radio" name="gender[]"  />female : <input type="radio" name="gender[]"  /><br />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="<?php echo $lang['63'];  ?>" onclick="formhash(this.form, this.form.password);"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

for name and family i did somthing like this for get just html entity with this pattern

```
$name = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+/", "", $name);
$family = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+/", "", $family);
```

and for email i did like this:

```
 $email = preg_replace("^[_a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\.[_a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3})$^", "", $email);
```

is this preg_replace secure enough or maybe i need using htmlentity or htmlspecailchars?

2-and for second question is it necessary to escape posted data which is from radio buttons or sellect options and if its necessary how should i escape them?

3-i just read about htmlpurifier..now if i have status field which user can i update it should i use html purifier for people statuses and this register form maybe?

thanks in advance.

Comment: every data coming from the user needs to be handled.

Comment: no one has answer for this question?:(

Comment: or the question is not clear

Comment: thanks ill improve question

Comment: See http://html5sec.org/ -- it has a massive list of possible hacks, along with how to avoid them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- It is better to escape all submitted values
- [HTMLPurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org) is a very good and enough to prevent XSS attacks, and here is how you can use it.

  ```
  # In register.php page:

  require_once 'path/to/HTMLPurifier/library/HTMLPurifier.auto.php';

  $config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
  $config->set('HTML.Doctype', 'HTML 4.01 Transitional');
  $config->set("HTML.Allowed", ""); // this will NOT allow any html tags
  $purifier = new HTMLPurifier($config);

  # hash the provided password (don't apply HTMLPurifier on the password)
  $hash_password = sha1($_POST["password"]);

  $data = array();

  # apply HTMLPurify on all submitted data
  foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
      $data["$key"] = mysql_real_escape_string($purifier->purify($value));
  }

  # get birthday
  $data["birthday"] = $data["year"] . "-" . $data["month"] . "-" . $data["day"];

  # insert submitted data into your database
  $result = mysql_query("
      INSERT INTO table_name (name, family, email, password, birthday, gender)
      VALUES ('{$data["name"]}', '{$data["family"]}', '{$data["email"]}', '$hash_password', '{$data["birthday"]}', '{$data["gender"]}')
  ");


  ?>
  ```

NOTE:
use `male` and `female` as values of the `name` attributes of the 2 radio input tags instead of the `gender[]` array

Comment: You shouldn't use mysql_ functions any longer as they are in the process of being depreciated, you should instead use either mysqli, or better IMHO PDO.  Just saying :)

Comment: @FireCrakcer37 You are absolutely right, and I'm already in my way to move to PDO because php.net itself says "Use of this extension (meaning mysql) is discouraged. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used"